# how to divide a line using split ()

Tags: java, regex, split, readline

help !!I want to divide into a group a line like in the following example

"http://data.doremus.org/performance/aa692091-a77c-3ef4-ba47-e1f9596d7b0c","Solistes d'aujourd'hui, solistes de demain - Festival de Jérusalem, Elena Bashkirova",2009-01-09

```
int i=0;
while ((CurrentLine = reader1.readLine()) != null) {

  String[] tokens = CurrentLine.split("\",");

  fichier1[i][0] =tokens[tokens.length-1].split("T"[0];//date

  fichier1[i][1] =tokens[tokens.length-2];//titre

  fichier1[i][2] =tokens[tokens.length-3];//URI
  i++;
}
```

I used the code on it, except that the element 2 (title) itself contains commas reading is wrong

Answer (score 4):

This looks like Comma Separated Value data, so why not use CSV parser for it? With http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ your code can look like:

```
String data = "\"http://data.doremus.org/performance/aa692091-a77c-3ef4-ba47-e1f9596d7b0c\",\"Solistes d'aujourd'hui, solistes de demain - Festival de Jérusalem, Elena Bashkirova\",2009-01-09";
CSVParser parser = new CSVParserBuilder().build();
String[] tokens = parser.parseLine(data);
for (String token : tokens){
    System.out.println("token = "+token);
}
```

output:

```
token = http://data.doremus.org/performance/aa692091-a77c-3ef4-ba47-e1f9596d7b0c
token = Solistes d'aujourd'hui, solistes de demain - Festival de Jérusalem, Elena Bashkirova
token = 2009-01-09
```

---

If you don't want to use external libraries one of simplest solution *for this case* would be instead of looking for place to split, looking for part which you are interested in, like

- text between quotes,
- sequence of non-comma outside of quotes.

For instance:

```
String data = "\"http://data.doremus.org/performance/aa692091-a77c-3ef4-ba47-e1f9596d7b0c\",\"Solistes d'aujourd'hui, solistes de demain - Festival de Jérusalem, Elena Bashkirova\",2009-01-09";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]+\"|[^,]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println("token = "+m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
token = "http://data.doremus.org/performance/aa692091-a77c-3ef4-ba47-e1f9596d7b0c"
token = "Solistes d'aujourd'hui, solistes de demain - Festival de Jérusalem, Elena Bashkirova"
token = 2009-01-09
```